# Wordpress - Force logout user when he goes to the homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, function, authentication, logout

I'm building a site with one page for each different client, and the structure is almost ready, but I'm facing a little problem right now.

My home page has the login and password module, when the user log-in, he automatically is redirected to his own page, showing his personal information.

I'm looking for a code that, when the user leaves his own page, he automatically is log-out from the site, getting redirected to the login page again.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,

Comment: well - if he is not on his own page, and not on the login page, and is logged in, call `<?php wp_logout(); ?> `

Comment: This is a frustrating design. You should make the homepage redirect to their page if they are logged in and redirect their page to the homepage if they are logged out. Don't auto-log-out your users.

Comment: Agree with @Kallmanation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Remember!, if you are logged in as admin, then this code won't work, try to login as subscriber or any other role except admin or you can create a new user role(except Admin :) )

```php
<?php
    if(is_front_page() && !current_user_can('administrator')){
        wp_destroy_current_session();
        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
        wp_set_current_user( 0 );
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.